# How to integrate tumblr?

Tags: iphone, tumblr

I am trying to integrate tumblr into my iphone application. went through number of document and git project none of them are helpful even tumblr documentation is not explaining clearly .please give me some reference so that i can figure it out, How to integrate tumble in iphone application

I went through [this git project](https://github.com/felipesabino/ios-tumblr-sdk), even after providing right credentials not able to login might be framework is outdated,

I'm unable to figure out how to integrate tumble in iphone application.

Please help me.

Comment: Most of the tumblr integration SO post are very old none of them are working.